# Do you recommend hiding elements with Javascript?

Tags: responsive-design

Are custom website loaders considered a good or bad practice ? If so, what would be the best way to implement one on a website?

Comment: What you're asking, having a loader that hides everything in a noscript-accessible website, is pretty much impossible. Only way I can think of to do that would be a dirty hack using css animations (have the loader be fixed and take up the entire viewport, then fade it out after a bit).

Comment: Back to the early 2000s with flash loading screens. :)

Comment: On your loader use `positions:fixed` `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` in css. That way it will cover the screen no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont recommend this, as this is not default userinterface and users often dont respond well to uncommon things. Also, the rendering of the html elements (the DOM) is very fast, but when you hide it, that doesn't happen.

Load screens are *not* common for a reason: They're user unfriendly.

The DOM loads fast, it's resources that slow it down. So find out how you can fix this. In your code you wait 2sec, that is not much. All you need to do is improve it to be more acceptable. Some options:

- Easy

  - Minimize filesize. Minify your javascript and css. Also reduce image sizes. You can make them smaller if they're very large, and/or use services like [Kraken.io](https://kraken.io/web-interface)
  - Move javascript and css which doesnt need to be rendered/parsed instantly to the end of the document, right before your `</body>`
- Medium

  - Load resources smart. Everything offscreen does not need to be loaded instantly, so control your loading in a way that those only load when the resources on the screen are done.
  - Control you cache. This will not fix the first load, but all visits after that will increase significantly.
  - Minimize resources. Are there parts you can fix with e.g. css? Is your css/javascript up to date and/or can re refactor code so it becomes less in size, or less in resource requirements?

---

To answer you actual question: No, I would not do it like that. But, if you want to do this (for whatever reason), make a (transparent) overlay over your site, with the loader over that. Then, don't use a timer (slow connections take longer), but use `$(window).load(function(){/* magic here */})`

Comment: Thanks for all the advice . Only reason I was going to do a load screen was to add a little 'pizazz ' to my portfolio. After hearing how bad it is, screw that. Thanks everyone again for the help .

Answer (score 0):

You should use [jQuery's addClass method](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to apply styles to elements that need their styles altered by javascript. Keep all of the styles in you CSS and then just apply the class with javascript.

As for animations. There shouldn't be anything wrong with using jQuery's fadeIn or fadeOut. [jQuery's animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is also really powerful if you want to use that.